# Retrieve HR-bpm with Google-Fit sensor api

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit

I am using an external device which is suppose to send `TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM` to the `SENSORS_API`.
I can retrieve steps with this code:

Client

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ApLifeAid.getAppContext())
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

Request

```
SensorRequest request = new SensorRequest.Builder()
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
```

And then using `Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mClient, request, this);`. In this case `this` is a class dedicated for sensor api in a service.

But I can't seem to get any values at all, `onDataPoint()` does not run, when I change my request to:

```
SensorRequest request = new SensorRequest.Builder()
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
            .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
```

If anybody knows what the problem is please tell me. And if you can see anything else that is weird in my code please tell me that too.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using the Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources to know if the heart rate sensor is available to your app ?

Comment: I am not. I've been trying to find a good resource for using the Fitness API but I am unable to find one. The official one is inconclusive and segmented.
Will give it a look when I get back to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently I need to find and then register the source I want the data to come from.

so I still use the "same" construction of the client, requests etc. but instead of using `SensorsApi.add` I use `findDataSources`. (Also, `FITNESS_BODY_READ` seemed more accurate and works well)

```
private void buildSensors() {
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ApLifeAid.getAppContext())
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    DataSourcesRequest dataSourcesRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM/*,
                    DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA*/)
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW) // data type, raw or derived?
            .build();

    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, dataSourcesRequest).setResultCallback(this);
}
```

The `setResultCallback(this)` then calls the following where I find an eligible source and add a listener and a sampling rate for it.

```
@Override
public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
    // On New Source Result
    for (final DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {

        // Request updates from this source, samplingRate
        SensorRequest sensorRequest = new SensorRequest.Builder()
                .setDataSource(dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
                .setDataType(dataSource.getDataType()) // Can't be omitted.
                .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        Log.i(TAG, "Fitness.SensorsApi.add for " + dataSource.toString() + " and type " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());
        Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mClient, sensorRequest, this)
                //Can be removed later
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) { // This might be important later on "Cannot register listener to source"
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to register listener for source: " + dataSource.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

This is now the simplest and cleanest way of reading heart rate that I've found ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check your Datasource is available or not.
If Datasource is not available and your sensor is bluetooth classic device and also does not support bluetooth GATT profile then you need to implement FitnessSensorService for registering your Datasource.

You can read about  FitnessSensorService from the following link.
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/new-sensors

Comment: I did not end up using a FitnessSensorService, but I did not use the findDataSources. Will post my solution